# Safely storing bank account information on parse?

Tags: encryption, parse-platform, pci-compliance

I'm using Parse as a back end.  I'd like to send money to users' bank accounts using ACH, but to do that I need access to their bank account information recurrently.  So, I'd like to store the information (encrypted) on the Parse server, so that I can credit users' bank accounts accordingly.  PCI-compliance, although suggested in this instance, is not required because obviously this has nothing to do with the Payment *Card* Industry...

That being said, how would one go about safely storing such sensitive data on the parse servers?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, i wouldn't store bank account data on any machine that's accessible via the internet.  At least, not unless that server was unable to decrypt it. (I might be a bit paranoid.  But the last thing i'd want is a news story about how my site got hacked and they made off with a bunch of bank account numbers.)

Comment: Be really careful and make sure ONLY the master key can access this data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Spreedly http://www.spreedly.com/

You can have a form that posts to spreedly (or just ajax to send to their API)
and they give you a token back. You can then run a charge on the token anytime. Very good service.

There are other tokenizing services like this.